# Questions regarding reversible and irreversible machines

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, potential-energy, reversibility

I was going through Feynman's argument of reversible and irreversible machines regarding gravitational potential energy. The lecture is right [here](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html). I have understood what he is trying to claim, but there are little details that he doesn't mention, but are very confusing for me.

My first question is:

> How do these machines work?

Although its a theoritical situation, its important to know how do they work. Do we provide some kind of manual force, because otherwise, the pans will not move at all, as the forces on both pans are balanced.

> How can we use a machine in a backward direction?

In his assumption of $Y>X$, he says 'use machine $A$ running in opposite direction'. Why and how? A machine can only be used starting from its initial condition, right? So how is he using it in the opposite direction?

> How can he assume that transferring of objects doesn't use any energy?

I don't really understand this point. It seems like, he is using some properties of potential energy, which he hasn't proved yet from his perpetual motion axiom.

> Finally, why are actual machines not reversible?

If we have a machine in real life, having two pans, initially balanced, having initial heights in level with each other(suppose $0$.) Then we move one pan to a height of $-1$, moving the other pan to a height of $X$. Now, if we reverse the process, then obviously the first pan has to come to the $0$ position, otherwise the string of the machine connecting the pans will just stretch, maybe break. So, why are actual machines of such sort not reversible?